# What the internal process followed by TableView to render its cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

What is the internal process followed by a TableView to render its cell, means if table view has an arbitrary number of cells say about 500 then how those cells are going to be rendered before the user

Comment: A table view only renders the currently visible cells.

Answer (score 1):

The cells are rendered one at a time, individually, and only when they need to be visible.  A tableview consists of just enough cells to always display the displayable content.  No other cells are rendered.  When one scrolls off the top, it's recycled and reused for the one that's about to scroll in from the bottom.

A table with 500 rows may never have more than 10-12 cells rendered at any given time, depending on the size of the tableview and the size of the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Cells are going to be rendered only when it will be visible in tableView, and disappear cells will be put in a container which can be reuse for the next appear cell with same `CellIdentifier`. So only the visible will be rendered in tableView. And the memory will be cost by cells depend on how many cells visible in tableview and how many `CellIdentifier` you have used in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to create new cells.

The following steps are the life cycle for cell:

1. Call `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
2. Call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to check the reusable cell with `CellIdentifier`.
    If return nil,  you should create a cell with a `CellIdentifier`.
    If not nil, you can reuse a cell without alloc. And the cell will invoke `prepareForReuse` which you can override the method in custom cell to reset UI.
3. After get a cell object, then will call `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` which you can customize the cell object before it is displayed.
4. When you scroll the tableview, and cell disappear from tableView. The cell will be put in a cache container, and ready to be reused for the next appearance, the time  when `delegate` call  `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` with same `CellIdentifier`.